# Retrieve all parent's children from Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child

I have a parent-child relationship and I am looking for a way to retrieve the children while searching on the parent.

In other words, I want to get all the posts of a user who's name is John.

I was trying to do the following but without any luck.

```
CRUD POST http://localhost/myIndex/user/_search  
{        
  "query": {  
    "bool": {
      name:"John",
      "has_child": {  
        "type": "post",  
        "query_all": {}  
      }
    }      
  }  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Here you find something on [ask] and on how to create a  [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
CRUD POST http://localhost/myIndex/post/_search  
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "type": "user", 
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "name": "John"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Checkout: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/has-parent.html

Comment: Sure, that would work. Unfortunately, my limitation is that I have to search on the parent (user).